# C++ Runtime Error on push_back for a vector of custom objects

Tags: c++, stdvector

In my class, when I try to push any object onto the vector myCache, I get a runtime error. I know I'm initializing the vector properly, and am stumped about why this is happening.

```
#ifndef CACHE_H
#define CACHE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "cacheblock.h"
using namespace std;

class Cache
{
  public:
   Cache(int rows, int numWords);
   ~Cache();
   CacheBlock getBlock(int index);

  private:
   vector<CacheBlock> *myCache;
};

#endif
```

and

```
Cache::Cache(int rows, int numWords)
{
   myCache = new vector<CacheBlock>;
   CacheBlock test(rows, 0, 0);
   myCache->push_back(test);

/*
   for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
   {
      myCache->push_back(test);
      cout << "inside loop\n\n";
   }
*/
}
```

CacheBlock.h:

```
class CacheBlock
{
  public:
   CacheBlock(int numWords, int newIndex, int tagNum);
   CacheBlock(const CacheBlock &newCacheBlock);
   ~CacheBlock();
   void setData(int numWords, int newIndex, int tagNum);

  private:
   bool valid;
   int index;
   int tag;
   vector<int> *dataWords;
};
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `CacheBlock` ? Sounds like there's some problem in the copy constructor of `CacheBlock`

Comment: What is the exact runtime error being received?

Comment: what does `CacheBlock` look like?

Comment: btw, is there a reason for allocating the `std::vector` on the heap(using `new` )?

Answer (score 5):

Presumably there is a working Copy Constructor for `CacheBlock`?

*EDIT*: thanks for posting the additional code.

If the destructor for `CacheBlock` cleans up the allocated `vector<int> *dataWords` by deletion, then the copy constructor will need to "deep copy" the vector of `dataWords`.  Without this deep copy, when the `CacheBlock` is copied, there will be two instances of `CacheBlock` with the same pointer to the `vector<int>`.  When the first instance is cleaned up, the second one will end up with a stray pointer to the now-deleted copy.

It's worthy of mention, as implied by the comment asking why the `vectors<>` are being allocated from the heap, that had they not been allocated from the heap, but had been mere member variables, none of these problems would have occurred.

To wit:

```
#ifndef CACHE_H
#define CACHE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "cacheblock.h"
using namespace std;

class Cache
{
  public:
   Cache(int rows, int numWords);
   // no longer need a destructor, as the auto-generated one by the compiler suffices
   // ~Cache();
   // potential optimization to return by const reference, rather than by copy
   const CacheBlock& getBlock(int index) const;

  private:
   vector<CacheBlock> myCache;
};

#endif
```

and

```
Cache::Cache(int rows, int numWords)
{
   // no longer need to construct the vector
   // myCache = new vector<CacheBlock>;
   CacheBlock test(rows, 0, 0);
   myCache->push_back(test);
}
```

CacheBlock.h:

```
class CacheBlock
{
  public:
   CacheBlock(int numWords, int newIndex, int tagNum);
   // no longer need a copy constructor
   // CacheBlock(const CacheBlock &newCacheBlock);
   // no longer need a destructor, as the compiler-generated one will suffice
   // ~CacheBlock();
   void setData(int numWords, int newIndex, int tagNum);

  private:
   bool valid;
   int index;
   int tag;
   vector<int> dataWords;
};
```

Comment: Ah, no there's not. I'm gonna write one for it now.

Comment: @Jon - depends on your class, you may need no such. Post `CacheBlock` class (only the interface, for the first time)

Comment: `CacheBlock` also contains a vector-pointer, `dataWords`.  The copy constructor needs to take that into account, as does its destructor.

Comment: My destructor takes care of dataWords, but what should the copy constructor do with it? Pass the pointer or pass the value?

Comment: The copy constructor needs to deep-copy the vector by allocating a new one, and populating it with the same data as in the original.

Comment: I just realized this XD. I commented out the deletion of the vector and realized what was happening.

Comment: 1 more thing, so this statement:

    dataWords = new vector<int>(c.dataWords);
isn't working, and I looked at the copy constructor for a vector. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: approximately `dataWords = new vector<int>(c.dataWords->begin(), c.dataWords->end());`

Comment: But seriously, why use heap-allocated vector of int, anyway?

Comment: Also, I guess I misunderstood what vector did. What I'm seeing by your changes is that vector stores stuff internally on heap, making it pointless to initialize the variable the way i was doing it?

Comment: Thanks a ton, I understand better what's happening here, and my code is fixed.

Comment: Or if you want to really share the underlying cache between the objects you could use shared_ptr or make it static. Static does not belong to the object so it will not be affected by the copy constructor. And if you use a shared_ptr a default constructor will do what it should so no need to define one. However if your intention was to make a copy of dataWords for every instance then you either have to define a copy constructor which would explicitly create a copy or just store the vector in the object rather the pointer to it.